# Nexus 7 (2013) Won't Boot Normally or into Recovery After Attempted Root

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, 4.3-jelly-bean

So I thought it would be a great idea to try and root my brand new 2013 Nexus 7. After checking out a few tutorials online, I found one for mac, and downloaded the toolkit at:

http://www.androidrootz.com/2012/12/nexus-7-one-click-toolkit-for-mac.html

I opened up the bootloader by holding down Power + Volume Down and opened the included script on my computer, which unlocked the device. I then attempted to restart it into recovery mode. I pressed Power + Volume Down on startup and opened up the bootloader. I then scrolled to Recovery Mode using the volume keys and pressed Power to select it and boot into recovery.

This is where everything went downhill.

I could open up the bootloader, but when I attempted to boot into recovery to load SuperSU onto my device, it got stuck on the Google logo with an unlocked padlock icon at the bottom of the screen. So I tried to boot normally, and it got stuck on the same screen.

All the forum posts I have come across so far to fix a bootloop all require the ability to boot into recovery mode or normally. I cannot find a guide that tells me how to relock and return to factory settings if I cannot boot at all.

Basically I need to unbrick my 2013 Nexus 7.

Comment: "I then attempted to restart it into recovery mode." What exactly did you do? What buttons did you press, etc.? You won't see the Google logo while it's booting into recovery.

Comment: I pressed Power + Volume Down on startup and opened up the bootloader. I then scrolled to Recovery Mode using the volume keys and pressed Power to select it and boot into recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've taken the liberty of editing that information into your question. All the important information should be in the question itself: comments are for requesting clarification and other temporary purposes. I guess it doesn't matter so much now you've solved the problem, but bear it in mind for next time! Don't forget to come back and mark your question as answered, so other visitors can see you've solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank god I figured out how to fix it.

The problem was that I was using software that was meant to root a first gen Nexus 7, and I had the second gen (2013) version. Whoops.

In order to fix it, I downloaded the Unroot/Stock Toolkit from
http://www.androidrootz.com/2013/08/nexus-7-one-click-toolkit-for-mac-2013.html

and then downloaded the factory images for the Nexus 7 2013 from Google's site,
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razor

I then used the Unroot/Stock Toolkit to reload the bootloader and factory image. After this, my Nexus worked fine. I was still able to root, but this time I made sure to use the correct software to do so.